# nuxt js store loses id on fresh

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

i am using store in nuxt js to store id of an item so that i can view details of the item, this is because i have two dashboard, the admin dashboard and the item dashboard,
so the problem am having is anytime i refresh the browser the store loses id, what am i doing wrong?

action in store  code

```
 makeitemId({commit},payload){
          commit('makehouseId',payload)
        },
```

am dispatching the makitemid everytime a user clicks on item which hence updates my store

Answer (score 0):

you should use ***vuex-persistedstate*** with **vuex**

so install by using below command

> npm install vuex-persistedstate

and use like this in store into index.js

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

const store = new Vuex.Store({

  plugins: [createPersistedState()]

//write your mutation , dispatcher and getters stuff
})
```

so, now everything will be exist after refreshing